# Greater/Lower than works but equals doesn't on >= and <= on .where()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 4 app and I'm trying to make a simple search for my invoices with 3 optional arguments: Name of the client, Start Date, End Date.

The search works fine mostly, if I put a start date and an end date it works for < and >, but eventhough i used >= and <=, if the invoice date is the same to either start or end, it just won't show on the result list.

The tables used look like this:

```
    Client Table
       ID
       Name
       The rest of the fields aren't necessary

    Invoice Table
       ID
       Client_ID
       Total_Price
       Created_At *only here for relevance*
```

My Invoice Controller Search method looks like this:

```
    def search
      if request.post?
        @count = 0
        @invoices = Invoice.all
        if params[:start_date].present?
          @invoices = Invoice.invoices_by_date(@invoices, params[:start_date], 'start')
          if @invoices.present?
            @count = 1
          else
            @count = 2
          end
        end
        if params[:end_date].present?
          @invoices = Invoice.invoices_by_date(@invoices, params[:end_date], 'end')
          if @invoices.present?
            @count = 1
          else
            @count = 2
          end
        end
        if params[:name].present?
          @invoices = Invoice.invoices_by_client(@invoices, params[:name])
          if @invoices.present?
            @count = 1
          else
            @count = 2
          end
        end
        if @count == 2
          flash.now[:danger] = "No results found."
          @invoices = nil
        end
        @name = params[:name]
        @start_date = params[:start_date]
        @end_date = params[:end_date]
      end
    end
```

And the Invoice Model methods i use look like this:

```
    def self.invoices_by_client(invoices, name)
      invoices= invoices.includes(:client)
                       .select('invoices.created_at', 'invoices.total_price', 'clients.name')
                       .where("clients.name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
                       .references(:client)
      return invoices
    end

    def self.invoices_by_date(invoices, date, modifier)
      if modifier == 'start'
        invoices = invoices.includes(:client)
                         .select('invoices.created_at', 'invoices.total_price', 'clients.name')
                         .where("invoices.created_at >= ?", date)
                         .references(:client)
      elsif modifier == 'end'
        invoices = invoices.includes(:client)
                         .select('invoices.created_at', 'invoices.total_price', 'clients.name')
                         .where("invoices.created_at <= ? ", date)
                         .references(:client)
      end
      return invoices
    end
```

It probably isn't the best solution overall and I don't know if i did anything wrong so it would be great if you guys could help me with this.

Comment: The `<=` and `>=` consider not only the date but also the time, please check how to deal with dates in rails and you will find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Alejandro's advice and messed around with the time aswell as the date, something like this:

```
    if modifier == 'start'
      invoices = invoices.includes(:client)
                         .select('invoices.created_at', 'invoices.total_price', 'clients.name')
                         .where("invoices.created_at >= ?", "#{date} 00:00:00") // Added the start time
                         .references(:client)
     elsif modifier == 'end'
       invoices = invoices.includes(:client)
                          .select('invoices.created_at', 'invoices.total_price', 'clients.name')
                          .where("invoices.created_at <= ? ", "#{date} 23:59:59") // Added end time aswell
                          .references(:client)
     end
```

I forced the time for the start date as 00:00:00 and the time for the end date as 23:59:59 and it worked as desired. Thank you for the help man and i hope this helps other people!